# One environment variable available to python child process and another not

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

Assigning a multiline string to `FOO` works as expected:

```
$ read -d '' FOO <<"EOF"
> the content
> EOF
$ echo $FOO
the content
$ python -c "import os; print os.environ.get('FOO')"
the content
```

Seemingly the same thing with `FOO_BAR_BAZ` works differently:

```
$ read -d '' FOO_BAR_BAZ <<"EOF"
> the content
> EOF
$ echo $FOO_BAR_BAZ
the content
$ python -c "import os; print os.environ.get('FOO_BAR_BAZ')"
None
```

I either have a subtle error or a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you `export FOO` but not `export FOO_BAR_BAZ`? Environment variables will only be visible to child processes (like Python) if they've been exported.

Comment: great, thanks! will accept in a few. So, I can make the assignment with the `read -d '' FOO_BAR_BAZ` and then just `export FOO_BAR_BAZ` after that.